# Optimize Linq to SQL query, Group By multiple fields

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq-to-sql

My LINQ query contains the following Group By statement:

```
Group p By Key = New With { _
.Latitude = p.Address.GeoLocations.FirstOrDefault(Function(g) New String() {"ADDRESS", "POINT"}.Contains(g.Granularity)).Latitude, _
.Longitude = p.Address.GeoLocations.FirstOrDefault(Function(g) New String() {"ADDRESS", "POINT"}.Contains(g.Granularity)).Longitude}
```

The query works, but here is the SQL that the clause above produces

```
SELECT [t6].[Latitude]
            FROM (
                SELECT TOP (1) [t5].[Latitude]
                FROM [dbo].[GeoLocations] AS [t5]
                WHERE ([t5].[Granularity] IN (@p0, @p1)) AND ([t5].[AddressId] = [t2].[Addr_AddressId])
                ) AS [t6]
            ) AS [value], (
            SELECT [t8].[Longitude]
            FROM (
                SELECT TOP (1) [t7].[Longitude]
                FROM [dbo].[GeoLocations] AS [t7]
                WHERE ([t7].[Granularity] IN (@p2, @p3)) AND ([t7].[AddressId] = [t2].[Addr_AddressId])
                ) AS [t8]
            ) AS [value2]
```

I am not a SQL expert, but it looks to me that this is rather suboptimal translation. This should really be one query that selects Latitide and Longitude from the first record. Perhaps SQL Server Optimizer will take care of this. But is there a way to nudge Linq to generate a leaner SQL statement to begin with?

I tried the following, too..

```
Group p By Key = p.Address.GeoLocations.Where(Function(g) New String() {"ADDRESS", "POINT"}.Contains(g.Granularity)). _
Select(Function(g) New With {.Latitude = g.Latitude, .Longitude = g.Longitude}).FirstOrDefault
```

but this produced an error: "A group by expression can only contain non-constant scalars that are comparable by the server."

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to reply in c#...

Here's what you have, translated to c#:

```
List<string> params = new List<string>()
{ "Address", "Point" };

from p in people
group p by new {
  Latitude = p.Address.GeoLocations
    .FirstOrDefault(g => params.Contains(g.Granularity)).Latitude,
  Longitude = p.Address.GeoLocations
    .FirstOrDefault(g => params.Contains(g.Granularity)).Longitude
};
```

Here's a rewrite, using the `let` keyword.

```
from p in people
let loc = p.Address.GeoLocations
   .FirstOrDefault(g => params.Contains(g.Granularity))
group p by new
{
  Latitude = loc.Latitude,
  Longitude = loc.Longitude
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't used let keyword before. This is certainly more elegant than what I had. Surprisingly though, the SQL generated is the same. I am guessing at this point that this is just the way Linq to SQL always handles multiple group keys.